# Removing all punctuation except white spaces python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace all punctuation from a text, except whitespaces and without splitting the text. 
I have tried:

```
text=re.sub('\W+', '', text)
```

but it removes whitespace.
Any hint?

Comment: `\W+` removes much more than punctuation. It matches 1+ non-word (letter/digit/`_`) symbols. If you want to remove those but a whitespace, use `[^\w\s]+`.

Comment: Also, have a look at [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I would like to remove ONLY punctuation while keeping the whitespaces....

Comment: Whitespaces are not punctuation.

Comment: And yes, I would like to replace them with a zerolength string

Comment: You can also play with the conversion to ASCII to achieve this:
`accepted = range(48,57) + range(65, 91) + range(97,123) + [32]`

   `for word in original:
        if  ord(word) in accepted:
           without += word`